# Control Foundation 6 Dropdown Menu programatically

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

[Foundation 6 Dropdown Menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html)

From my attempts it looks like this cannot be controlled (open, close) programatically. I've tried to use a jQuery `click()` event on the element but nothing happens. I've seen many posts for version 5 to use the foundation open function:

```
$('ul.dropdown').foundation('open');
```

But that doesn't work for version 6.

Has anyone done this or is this a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code

```js
    $(document).foundation();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.dropdown > li.is-dropdown-submenu-parent > a:eq(0)').click();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compressed CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css">

<!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>


<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu data-click-open="true" data-disable-hover="true">
  <li class="is-dropdown-submenu-parent">
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3A</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="on-click"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

use this plugins
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html#js-options